# How to space html elements equally far from their center with css

Tags: html, css

I am just starting out with WebDev, so sorry if this is trivial.
I am looking for a way to equally space the links in my navigation bar, regardless of how long they are. So that, no matter how long the text of each link is, for 5 links the 3rd link is always perfectly centered on the page.

So far everything i found puts the same amount of space between each link.
Here's my code (simplified):

```css
/*-----------------------Original Code-------------------------*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.bar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.links {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
.links li {
    margin: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
}

/*-------------------Solution to my Problem---------------------*/
.links {
    /*set width to 100%, otherwise it's somehow smaller */
    width: 100%;
}
.links li {
    /*removed margin at the side, as it is now spaced with flex*/
    margin: 1em 0em 1em 0em;

    /*make all li the same size*/
    flex: 1;

    /* keep the text from wrapping and hide overflow,
    otherwise it would change the layout, by expanding to fit the li*/
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;

    /*align the Links within the li*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Problem</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bar">
        <ul class="links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Text</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Longer Text</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">#</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Even Longer Text</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">The Longest Text in the List</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by equally spaced. If there are 5 and the 3rd one is always to be centered in the middle then the spacing between the items is likely to have to differ if the texts are of different lengths. Could you clarify.

Comment: To clarify: I want an arbitrary amount of links to display next to each other. The distance between their middle lines have to be the same. (5 was just an example, because it's easy to visualize when there is an uneven amount of links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use other elements like table, then I have used [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)  so the third div will always be in the center because there are 5 divs in total.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Problem</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }
      .bar {
        background-color: grey;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .links {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .links li {
        margin: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .link1 {
        flex: 1;
      }
      .link2 {
        flex: 1;
      }
      .link3 {
        flex: 2;
      }
      .link4 {
        flex: 1;
      }
      .link5 {
        flex: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bar">
      <ul class="links">
        <li class="link1">
          <a href="#">Text</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link2">
          <a href="#">Longer Text</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link3">
          <a href="#">#</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link4">
          <a href="#">Even Longer Text</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link5">
          <a href="#">The Longest Text in the List</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is what i was looking for. Setting the width of `.links` and setting `flex: 1;` for `.links ul`. Can you explain why you used `flex: 2;` on the middle link? Wouldn't that make it scale to 2 times the size of the rest?

Comment: Also: Is it possible to have the same layout, but expand the links, if they are bigger and there is still room left?. Because this version just sets all `li` to the same size (which is fine, but if one link is very big, and another one is very small, the bigger  one is cut of, while there would have been room to expand further)

Comment: I set the width to 100%. You have 5 total links, that means they need to share this width so 20% each, but when one of them get's `flex-2` it means that he will get a 40% width while others will have 15%. Because they will share that 100% total width. For more please take a look at [Flex MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: I was just pointing out, that `flex: 2` on one link, wouldn't space them equally missing the point of my question. Also wouldn't it make one 33.3% and the others 16.7% ? My answer sounds kinda rude, that wasn't intended. Thanks for helping.

Comment: hmm if you want them equal can you check this link and let me know ? [Code In SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-burnell-2xvrr?file=/index.html)

Comment: I already found my solution (eventhough it's not perfect) and added it to my original question. The Code you had in the link doesnt center the "Center" div, so not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the text align property in the link style

```
.links {
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
text-align: center;
```

}

Comment: I think he wants the 3rd link in the absolute center of the page this code doesn't do that

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and shortes way to achieve it is the use of a CSS-grid. You dont even need to use a list then. You split the Navigation bar into 5 equal columns with `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);`. That way the center column will also always stay at the center.

```css
.bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
}

/* For demonstration only */
.demo-scale {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.demo-scale div {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.demo-scale div:nth-child(even) {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
}

.demo-scale div:nth-child(odd) {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <a href="#">Text</a>
  <a href="#">Longer Text</a>
  <a href="#">#</a>
  <a href="#">Even Longer Text</a>
  <a href="#">The Longest Text in the List</a>
</div>

<!-- For demonstration only -->
<div class="demo-scale">
  <div>10%</div>
  <div>20%</div>
  <div>30%</div>
  <div>40%</div>
  <div>50%</div>
  <div>60%</div>
  <div>70%</div>
  <div>80%</div>
  <div>90%</div>
  <div>100%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this scale for an arbitrary amount of links? Seems to me as if i would have to manually adjust the collums

Comment: well you can either use JS to count the elements and set the the grid-columns-amount according to it. Or you can use a 3 column amount where you need to declare the links to be either left or right side of the center and alsoc an declare which element needs to be centered

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `flex: 1;` for the `.links li` does the trick and is simpler

Answer (score -1):

If I got you right, I think you can use a `<table>` instead of the `<ul>`
with a `table-layout: fixed;` style

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
        }
        .bar {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: grey;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
      
        table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center; 
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Problem</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bar">
      <table>
      <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Text</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">Long Text</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">#</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">123</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">5346423</a></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dont use a table for styling purpose. Tables should only be used for displaying data. For styling purpose either use flexbox or css-grid which are modern solutions and have a few advantages over tables. For example allowing full repsonsiveness with layout changed for mobile use (media queries, grid-template-areas, flex-order...)